# Selenium PHP-webdriver cannot log-in to site. Is it a cookie issue?

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver

I'm very new to Selenium and attempting to use the PHP-webdriver Facebook version.

So far, all I want to do is log-in to a particular site. The log-in page is very basic with a username, password and Sign In button.

My code is:

```
$driver->get('https://login.example.com');


// adding cookie
$driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();
$driver->manage()->addCookie(array(
  'name' => 'cookie_name',
  'value' => 'cookie_value',
));

$cookies = $driver->manage()->getCookies();
print_r($cookies);

//enter login
enter_text($driver, 'email', 'example@example.com');

//enter password
enter_text($driver, 'password', 'abcde');

//log in
$search = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::tagName('button'));
$search->click();



    //function for entering text by id
    function enter_text($driver, $id, $text) {
        $search = $driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id($id));
        $search->click();
        $driver->getKeyboard()->sendKeys($text);
    }
```

The username and password are properly populated and it appears as if the Sign In button is being clicked. However, when I review the screenshot (just using Firefox as a headless browser), the results of the log-in says

'this session is no longer valid.'

Usually that means there is some kind of cookie issue. I'm much more used to Curl where cookies need to be explicitly managed. I assumed as Selenium is using a browser that cookies are handled automatically just like for a regular user. Am I wrong? If so, how would I use cookies here? Is there anything else that can cause the log-in to fail?

If it helps, I'm using AWS Linux.

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the screenshot? I'm not clear who/what is producing the 'this session is no longer valid' msg.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot. It basically displays exactly that message. It's the same type of message the user would get after refreshing the screen after being idle for too long. thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but there really isn't enough info here to allow people to help. Presumably you've tried without the cookies and deduced that there's something about one of the values that the server/sitecode is checking - but we have no visibility of any of that.

Comment: Yes, I have. My question really is what role cookies play here. I'm assuming I should not to manage any cookies because it's all done in a browser. If that's the case, then how could the behavior of Selenium be any different then the behavior of a regular user?

Comment: Well it's all HTTP: just as with curl you can seed a cookie store (but managed by the browser), it's just that the browser will pass them across requests, whether it's Selenium or a regular user driving. But ordinarily with Selenium we want to start with clean sessions, no cookies, unless there's particular behaviour we want to trigger (but then we might as well just use curl for that). There shouldn't be any particular mystery with Selenium's cookie handling.

Comment: I did get this to work with a full Firefox browser but not with a headless browser. Why would they be different?

Comment: Which one? I don't see how the graphics envt should affect cookie-handling, but each browser is bound to implement cookies slightly differently, especially the more obscure ones.

Comment: Also Firefox. On one machine I tried with headless firefox and the other with full firefox. I agree it doesn't make sense. I believe HTTP Only cookies may be causing this but I don't know much about this